# Find string pattern in file/input, Context dependent search, (not like grep)

Tags: linux, command-line, search, grep

Is there any utility available to find text, like in `grep` (linux) or `findstr` (dos), but to start looking only after another given text/pattern is found?

Like trying to find given text/pattern in a file, but only the ones that are inside particular section of the file that is. Only 'the file' in my case is an output from another program and amount of lines outputted is too many to write into a file and analyze it there.

example:

```
section ONE
  text_a
  text_b
  text_c
section TWO
  text_b
  text_c
section THREE
  . . .
```

find if any "text_c" in section TWO only.

I tried to read on `grep`'s options but it doesn't seem to have this ability.
This is expected also to minimize amount of string comparisons since "text_c" is much longer than section names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
section ONE
  text_a
  text_b
  text_c  <-ignore this
section TWO
  text_b
  text_c  <-keep this
section THREE
  text_a
  text_b
  text_c  <-ignore this
```

To select any line containing `text_c` that is in `section TWO`:

```
$ awk '/^section/{f=0} /^section TWO/{f=1} f && /text_c/' file
  text_c  <-keep this
```

If the input is generated not from a file but from `command`, then use:

```
command | awk '/^section/{f=0} /^section TWO/{f=1} f && /text_c/'
```

#### How it works

- `/^section/{f=0}`

  Anytime that we find a line beginning with `section`, set `f=0`.
- `/^section TWO/{f=1}`

  If the line starts with `section TWO`, then override the previous command and set `f=1`.
- `f && /text_c/`

  If `f` is nonzero and the current line matches `text_c`, then print the line.

Comment: **Great!** Now I need to find **Windows/Dos equivalent**, since sometimes the output comes from windows specific batch files and _cygwin(babun in my case)_ doesn't give **exactly** the same output...

Comment: Very good.  As for the DOS/Windows issues, your description lacks specificity but most of them can be solved with a `dos2unix`-like utility that will remove carriage return characters.

Comment: Line endings can be handled by changing regex I guess, if it causes trouble. But what I meant is ... just tried to run a batch file in _cygwin(babun)_ and some commands get weird prefixes in output: `%{)g[blue]%}{ %c }`...  which goes away with `@echo off` as first line though (not clear if anything else might got messed up.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but have anybody ever tried to compile any of useful Linux utilities for Win/Dos? Aren't they written in plain C?

Comment: I have no experience with that batch file issue.  There have been various collections of unix utilities ported to Win.  GnuWin32/GnuWin64 was one example.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with `sed` like:

```
command | sed -n -e '/section TWO/,/section THREE/ { /text_c/p;}'
```

this works by:

- `-n` tells `sed` not to print matching lines by default
- `-e` gives `sed` a script to work on

  - `/section TWO/,/section THREE/` sets our address range, so we are going to apply the next function to all the lines between the lines that match `section TWO` and `section THREE`
  - `{ /text_c/p;}` defines the function that will match a line with `text_c` and if it finds it will `p` print it

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Not useful for my case though. I don't have all the "section" names, only the ones that are of interest.      Upvote! (not enough reputation points yet to actually do it)

Comment: If section order were known, this would be a good approach.  So, as sny wanted to do: +1.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of lines that follow each section are somewhat constant, You can use the '-A*x*' option in grep to print *x* lines following a section match.
This can then be piped to a second grep that looks for your pattern within 'section TWO'.

```
$ cat file
section ONE
  1 text_a
  1 text_b
  1 text_c  
section TWO
  2_text_a
  2 text_b
  2 text_c  
section THREE
  3 text_a
  3 text_b
  3 text_c 

$ grep -A3 'section TWO' file | grep text_c
  2 text_c
```

Comment: Thank you. For me it was only once that I knew the number of lines though, all the other times it was unknown beforehand.